# Azure Functions Upgrade from beta to ~2 breaking existing code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We have been using Azure Function runtime version as "beta" and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs - version 3.0.0-beta5 package to bind with Eventhubs.

Things broke down completely after azure portal started prompting for Upgrading to version 2 for Azure Functions. With or without changing the runtime to ~2 (or any specific 2.x.x.x version) it is failing.

Can someone make it clear on what needs to change if we want to target version 2? I tried to upgrade Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to latest 1.0.19 and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs to latest 3.0.0-beta8. All I get is assembly loader errors!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the description of this breaking change and recommended steps in [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129).

Comment: As per this link, I had already tried updating the sdk and extension version to 1.0.19 and 3.0.0-beta8. But I get following assembly load error:  System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publ
icKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.